# MySql server is overloading due some php script,how to find which one?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem,mysql server start overloading,it is running like 120% CPU,how can I find php script that is making a problem? Can I do this ? What can I do if no,and if yes,how to find that script.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: google `mysql slow log` then search witch script executes the queryes

Comment: tnx,mysql slow log isn't enabled on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two quick things you can do to see what's actually happening. One is to run `top` via the command line and see if it's truly mysqld, or your php script which is causing the cpu load. The other is to issue the `show processlist` from MySQL command line to see if there are any long running queries which may be hanging things up. Chances are your PHP script is the culprit and not MySQL.

Comment: Hi I do not have access to mysql command line,I only have access to phpMyAdmin

Comment: Ahhh sorry, been several years since I have used phpMyAdmin. If you don't have access to the MySQL server, then the other posts referencing the 'slow query log' is your best bet.

Comment: Hi @Digital Precision,thank you for the response,still to see slow logs it looks like they should be enabled on the mysql server,and I can not do that either. Is there anything that I can do with SSH? maybe stupid question,but just need to check everything,and I'm not pro.

Comment: If you can SSH into the server, then chances are you can gain access to your MySQL server. Can you SSH to the server?

Comment: Hmmm,well I didn't use SSH yet,but I have SSH access.I have just enabled SSH access on server

Comment: So SSH to your server, then you can issue a command to connect to your mysql server `mysql -u user_name -h host_name -p`, you will then be prompted for a password, then you should be able to issue the `show processlist` command, which will show you all currently running queries. So if you run your php script, you can run this command and see if the queries are your problem, or the PHP script.

Comment: I have connect to server with SSH,but I do not know what now?Can you help me on chat with this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4704/discussion-between-digital-precision-and-user303832)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where exactly - but in PHPMyAdmin somewhere in the server's information there are the slow queries section - take a look at them

Comment: I'm looking there,it looks like mysql slow log isn't enabled.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that I saw it in there but now I can't find where it is, but it might be because I've logged in with normal user. anyway - if you have the right permissions you can query this: `SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.slow_log;`

Comment: When I try to execute that query I get #1142 - SELECT command denied to user,... tnx for the response @Joe Polico

Comment: As I said - you'll need the right permissions to run this query, and I guess that this is the reason why the slow query section didn't showed in your PHPMyAdmin